# No directory for github.io problems with jekyll

Tags: bash, github, terminal, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am creating my github.io I had a lot of problems, at first, but eventually was able to install rbenv and jekyll using this:

```
gem install jekyll --user-install
```

Now I tried to run

```
cd abrhor.github.com
```

and

```
cd abrhor.github.io
```

but the return was:

```
-bash: cd: github.abrhor.io: No such file or directory
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do. I can insert my Terminal session if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [front page of Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), you seem to be missing the intermediate step:

```
jekyll new abrhor.github.io
```

Then you can cd into the created local site.

Comment: You mean `jekyll new abrhor.github.io` ?